# c# Function to accept and process Object of Type T

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I am writing a custom method which will Pro-Rate a value across a specific property of List of items

```
private List<Model1> UniformDistribute(List<Model1> inputList, decimal amountToDistribute, decimal total)
{
    
    decimal totalRemaining = total;
    
    foreach (Model1 item in inputList)
    {  
        item.TotalVal = Math.Round(item.BaseValue + (item.BaseValue * amountToDistribute), 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);                                 
        totalRemaining -= item.TotalVal;
    }
    
    if (totalRemaining != 0)
    {
        inputList.LastOrDefault().TotalVal += totalRemaining;
    }
    return inputList;
}
```

This method pro-Rate the value to property TotalVal of a list of type Model1

I have couple of other models of different types like Model2 Model3 etc exists  with same properties used inside this method ( TotalVal & BaseValue ) and some other different  properties

Can we make the method UniformDistribute as a generic one which can be called with any models Model2 / Model3 to avoid same code repetition using C#

I was trying to make it as below , but not sure how can i access properties inside foreach  specific to Model1 / Model2/Model3 etc based on the type of Model the inputList is based on

```
private IEnumerable<T> UniformDistribute<T>(IEnumerable<T> inputList, decimal amountToProrate, decimal total)
{ 
    foreach (var item in inputList)
    {           
    }
}
```

Comment: Do they have a common base class or a common interface to expose their common properties?

Comment: ATM  there is no common interface to expose the common properties  One of  them is exposed to CSVHelper and i am afraid it is possible to handle that for CSVHelper as column headings etc are defined on top of properties

Comment: You need to put all the common properties into an interface (maybe called `IModel`) and then change your Model classes to implement that interface. Then you can change the type `T` to `IModel` (in your `UniformDistribute` implementation).

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think a generic constraint would be more appropriate, so that the specific model type can still be returned: `where T : IModel`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Model1` type makes use of a property called `TotalVal` that it reads and writes, and makes use of a property called `BaseValue` that it reads.  To make this *generic*, that type will need to be *constrained* to at least an interface that defines what `TotalVal` getters and setters do and what a `BaseValue` getter does.

Specify this with a generic type constraint `where T: IModel`.  See [documentation for `where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint).

Then all your concrete Model classes should implement the `IModel` interface.

Minimally something like this:

```
interface IModel {
    decimal TotalVal { get; set; }
    decimal BaseValue { get; }
}

class SomeClass
{
    private static List<T> UniformDistribute<T>(List<T> inputList,
        decimal amountToDistribute, decimal total) where T : IModel
    {

        decimal totalRemaining = total;

        foreach (T item in inputList) {
            item.TotalVal = Math.Round(item.BaseValue + 
                (item.BaseValue * amountToDistribute), 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
            totalRemaining -= item.TotalVal;
        }

        if (totalRemaining != 0) {
            inputList.LastOrDefault().TotalVal += totalRemaining;
        }
        return inputList;
    }
}
```